# Collector for ArcGIS PDOP and GPS collection configuration settings

Tags: gps, accuracy, arcgis-collector

My company just acquired a Geneq SXBlue II GPS receiver to pair with an iPad and the Collector for ArcGIS app.  The functionality is awesome and loved by everyone, but since we have  biologists on our team, they need to know the PDOP per point collected to ensure that it is below 6 to meet minimum standards.

I am basically wondering if/where there is the ability to control GPS collection configuration settings in Collector for ArcGIS, as described in the following support article about ArcGIS Mobile:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/help/index.html#//007v0000000v000000.htm

I first started checking with the GPS receiver unit configuration settings to see if I could at least set a threshold to only collect points if the PDOP is under 6; however, I have been unsuccessful.  I next began to ponder that since I want these values per point collected, that maybe the setting was at the shapefile-level.

Comment: for iOS you will need your own app to restrict your PDOP to <6 here is a sample for starters https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-ios/tree/master/GPSSketchingSample see Accuracy sceenshot

Comment: Can you provide additional explanation? Is this an app that I can download (that restricts the PDOP)?  The points collected in the Collector for ArcGIS app uses the location information of the SXBlue GPS receiver.  The GPS itself comes with an app of it's own, but I have yet to find where to change that setting (I have a couple e-mails out to their support team).

Comment: $JMASK,10 change to 6 Page57 http://sxbluegps.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/SXBlue-II-GPS-Series-Manual_rev231.pdf