# Field Equipment: Geneq SXBlue II with iPad and ArcGIS Collector app

Tags: gps, ipad, arcgis-collector

My company just recently purchased a Geneq SXBlue II GNSS receiver to be pair with an iPad and the Collector for ArcGIS app.  I have heard great things about the submeter accuracy of the unit; however, the biologists on my team want the ability to see the PDOP per point and want the GPS to only capture the point if it meets a certain PDOP threshold, just like our Trimble GeoXT unit does.  I believe there is an ability to change the PDOP threshold on the GPS receiver, but does anyone have experience with how or if the Collector app lets you know if the threshold has not been met? Does it simply not take the point? Give you a message?

Comment: Duplicate Question? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131022/collector-for-arcgis-pdop-and-gps-collection-configuration-settings

Comment: Looks like GNSS metadata will be supported at 10.4. https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/05/03/collector-for-arcgis-10-4-beta/

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Collector GIS doesn't make use of GNSS metadata and it will not report estimated accuracy less than 1 meter.  The SXB2GNSS is only a gps/gnss receiver and provides no control over if a point is taken or not, regardless of PDOP...that is the software's function.  ESRI is, from what I hear, updating Collector to use GNSS metadata (PDOP, etc) to report estimated accuracy below a meter...i.e. submeter.  If you want to be sure your PDOP threshold isn't exceeded, you can use BT GPS app (for Android OS) found at Google Play and/or Lefebure's NTRIP client from their website.  Both are free apps and can run alongside Collector...just have to switch back/forth before each point is taken.  I heard Collector will be updated sometime in March??